# Matlab2022a crashed after updating Windows11

Tags: matlab

Today I updated my Windows11 to the new version".NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8" and tried to open the file I created in Simulink. Then Matlab2022a crashed and the report shows that:

```
Configuration:
  Crash Decoding           : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode               : continue (default)
  Default Encoding         : UTF-8
  Deployed                 : false
  Graphics Driver          : Uninitialized hardware 
  Graphics card 1          : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 Version 27.20.100.8854 (2020-10-14)
  Graphics card 2          : NVIDIA ( 0x10de ) NVIDIA GeForce MX150 Version 30.0.15.1169 (2022-2-1)
  Java Version             : Java 1.8.0_202-b08 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  MATLAB Architecture      : win64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID    : 870270
  MATLAB Root              : D:\matlab2022a
  MATLAB Version           : 9.12.0.1927505 (R2022a) Update 1
  OpenGL                   : hardware
  Operating System         : Microsoft Windows 11 家庭中文版
  Process ID               : 18352
  Processor ID             : x86 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
  Session Key              : d051bbab-4643-4827-882b-4e0bd09fab72
  Window System            : Version 6.0 (Build 6001: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Current Thread: 'MCR 0 interpreter thread' id 9648

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000002  RBX = 0000014500827750
  RCX = 00007ffe1e8450b8  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 000000369d2f48f0  RBP = 000000369d2f49f0
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 000000369d2f4b30
 
   R8 = 00000000496f2eed   R9 = 00000000562eb25b
  R10 = 0000000000000000  R11 = 000000369d2f48e0
  R12 = 000001450273d4f0  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 00000144d5b5ce40
 
  RIP = 00007ffdbee6be16  EFL = 00010246
 
   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007ffdbee6be16             D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\sl_editor.dll+08306198 Simulink::StudioSpawningInfo::studioApp+00015286
[  1] 0x00007ffdbee6c9c4             D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\sl_editor.dll+08309188 Simulink::StudioSpawningInfo::studioApp+00018276
[  2] 0x00007ffdbee6ecfb             D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\sl_editor.dll+08318203 Simulink::StudioSpawningInfo::studioApp+00027291
[  3] 0x00007ffdd1f8d6cb         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+14079691 SlGraphDomainTypeReg::registerDomainType+00008107
[  4] 0x00007ffdd1f8f192         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+14086546 RemoveBlockFromGraph+00006242
[  5] 0x00007ffdf3e2a3fd  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\sl_graphical_classes.dll+03777533 slGraph::open+00000429
[  6] 0x00007ffdd18dbe30         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07061040 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00006704
[  7] 0x00007ffdd18dc870         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07063664 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00009328
[  8] 0x00007ffdd18dc987         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07063943 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00009607
[  9] 0x00007ffdd18da59b         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07054747 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00000411
[ 10] 0x00007ffdd18dc5f7         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07063031 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00008695
[ 11] 0x00007ffdd18dc7c2         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07063490 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00009154
[ 12] 0x00007ffdd18dc987         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07063943 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00009607
[ 13] 0x00007ffdd18dac1f         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07056415 SLGlue::WindowingService::~WindowingService+00002079
[ 14] 0x00007ffdd1939673         D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwsimulink.dll+07444083 slFullOpenSys+00000499
[ 15] 0x00007ffe17f79605               D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\builtin.dll+00103941 MathWorks::builtin::BuiltinFcn::invoke+00001157
[ 16] 0x00007ffe191b6b49                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00093001 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001449
[ 17] 0x00007ffe191b6a55                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00092757 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001205
[ 18] 0x00007ffe191b6262                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090722 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000738
[ 19] 0x00007ffe191b5fad                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090029 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000045
[ 20] 0x00007ffe189a1324  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00332580 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00071588
[ 21] 0x00007ffe189af720  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00390944 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00129952
[ 22] 0x00007ffe153b1721                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05510945 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00006097
[ 23] 0x00007ffe153b2a29                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05515817 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00010969
[ 24] 0x00007ffe153079b8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04815288 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00279032
[ 25] 0x00007ffe1531f889                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04913289 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00377033
[ 26] 0x00007ffe1511bbab                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02800555 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsIfElse+00522971
[ 27] 0x00007ffe15120074                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02818164 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00012660
[ 28] 0x00007ffe1511d601                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02807297 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00001793
[ 29] 0x00007ffe151211b5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02822581 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017077
[ 30] 0x00007ffe15121463                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02823267 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017763
[ 31] 0x00007ffe15120db8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02821560 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00016056
[ 32] 0x00007ffe1511cda6                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02805158 MathWorks::lxe::LxeTypes::GetTypeXvalueOf+00000598
[ 33] 0x00007ffe151eb3e5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03650533 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00043317
[ 34] 0x00007ffe151eef60                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03665760 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00058544
[ 35] 0x00007ffe18a6f830  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+01177648 FeatureTestObservableWorkspace+00186352
[ 36] 0x00007ffe189dbc7e  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00572542 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00069966
[ 37] 0x00007ffe189dd5bf  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00579007 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00076431
[ 38] 0x00007ffe18a53562  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+01062242 FeatureTestObservableWorkspace+00070946
[ 39] 0x00007ffe18a53173  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+01061235 FeatureTestObservableWorkspace+00069939
[ 40] 0x00007ffe18f82905                    bin\win64\pgo\m_interpreter.dll+00076037 inEvalIn+00000165
[ 41] 0x00007ffe17f79605               D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\builtin.dll+00103941 MathWorks::builtin::BuiltinFcn::invoke+00001157
[ 42] 0x00007ffe191b6b49                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00093001 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001449
[ 43] 0x00007ffe191b6a55                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00092757 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001205
[ 44] 0x00007ffe191b6262                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090722 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000738
[ 45] 0x00007ffe191b5fad                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090029 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000045
[ 46] 0x00007ffe189a1324  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00332580 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00071588
[ 47] 0x00007ffe189af720  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00390944 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00129952
[ 48] 0x00007ffe153b1721                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05510945 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00006097
[ 49] 0x00007ffe153b2a29                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05515817 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00010969
[ 50] 0x00007ffe153079b8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04815288 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00279032
[ 51] 0x00007ffe1531f889                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04913289 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00377033
[ 52] 0x00007ffe1511bbab                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02800555 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsIfElse+00522971
[ 53] 0x00007ffe15120074                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02818164 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00012660
[ 54] 0x00007ffe1511d601                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02807297 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00001793
[ 55] 0x00007ffe151211b5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02822581 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017077
[ 56] 0x00007ffe15121463                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02823267 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017763
[ 57] 0x00007ffe15120db8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02821560 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00016056
[ 58] 0x00007ffe1511cda6                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02805158 MathWorks::lxe::LxeTypes::GetTypeXvalueOf+00000598
[ 59] 0x00007ffe151eb3e5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03650533 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00043317
[ 60] 0x00007ffe151eef60                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03665760 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00058544
[ 61] 0x00007ffe18a6f830  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+01177648 FeatureTestObservableWorkspace+00186352
[ 62] 0x00007ffe18999ad2  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00301778 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00040786
[ 63] 0x00007ffe189994a5  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00300197 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00039205
[ 64] 0x00007ffe1899c1b8  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00311736 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00050744
[ 65] 0x00007ffe191b68a2                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00092322 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00000770
[ 66] 0x00007ffe191b654d                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00091469 Mfh_file::dispatch_with_reuse+00000045
[ 67] 0x00007ffe153d7d3e                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05668158 MathWorks::lxe::CreateNestedFunctionHandle+00008318
[ 68] 0x00007ffe189de1dd  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00582109 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00079533
[ 69] 0x00007ffe18a3933f  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00955199 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00452623
[ 70] 0x00007ffe18f79e49                    bin\win64\pgo\m_interpreter.dll+00040521 inFullFevalFcn+00000361
[ 71] 0x00007ffe17f79605               D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\builtin.dll+00103941 MathWorks::builtin::BuiltinFcn::invoke+00001157
[ 72] 0x00007ffe191b6b49                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00093001 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001449
[ 73] 0x00007ffe191b6a55                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00092757 AutoPushingExecutionFrame::~AutoPushingExecutionFrame+00001205
[ 74] 0x00007ffe191b6262                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090722 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000738
[ 75] 0x00007ffe191b5fad                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00090029 Mfh_MATLAB_fn_impl::dispatch+00000045
[ 76] 0x00007ffe189a1324  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00332580 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00071588
[ 77] 0x00007ffe189af720  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00390944 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_always_noconv+00129952
[ 78] 0x00007ffe153b1721                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05510945 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00006097
[ 79] 0x00007ffe153b2a29                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+05515817 MathWorks::lxe::ReadOnlyXvaluePtr::operator=+00010969
[ 80] 0x00007ffe153079b8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04815288 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00279032
[ 81] 0x00007ffe1531f889                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+04913289 MathWorks::lxe::printLxeProfStatsForFeature+00377033
[ 82] 0x00007ffe1511bbab                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02800555 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsIfElse+00522971
[ 83] 0x00007ffe15120074                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02818164 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00012660
[ 84] 0x00007ffe1511d601                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02807297 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00001793
[ 85] 0x00007ffe151211b5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02822581 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017077
[ 86] 0x00007ffe15121463                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02823267 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00017763
[ 87] 0x00007ffe15120db8                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02821560 MathWorks::lxe::LXEConstants::IsY+00016056
[ 88] 0x00007ffe1511cda6                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02805158 MathWorks::lxe::LxeTypes::GetTypeXvalueOf+00000598
[ 89] 0x00007ffe151eb3e5                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03650533 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00043317
[ 90] 0x00007ffe151eef60                 D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+03665760 MathWorks::lxe::SetEngineImplUnlinkFlagForAllCallsOnStack+00058544
[ 91] 0x00007ffe18a6f830  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+01177648 FeatureTestObservableWorkspace+00186352
[ 92] 0x00007ffe189dbc7e  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00572542 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00069966
[ 93] 0x00007ffe189dd5bf  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00579007 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00076431
[ 94] 0x00007ffe18a38cf6  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00953590 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00451014
[ 95] 0x00007ffe18a3aca7  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00961703 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00459127
[ 96] 0x00007ffe18a39dcc  D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwlxemainservices.dll+00957900 mwboost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<mwboost::archive::xml_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::PreLineExecutionEvent>::save_object_ptr+00455324
[ 97] 0x00007ffe18f86012                    bin\win64\pgo\m_interpreter.dll+00090130 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnInDesiredWSAndPublishEvents+00000074
[ 98] 0x00007ffe195061f5                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00745973 iqm::InternalEvalPlugin::inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000101
[ 99] 0x00007ffe19505b27                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00744231 iqm::InternalEvalPlugin::execute+00000247
[100] 0x00007ffeaeee2167             D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\nativejmi.dll+00336231 nativejmi::JmiIIP::serializeExplicit+00005431
[101] 0x00007ffeaef4280f             D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\nativejmi.dll+00731151 NativeLabCmdWinSetup+00388175
[102] 0x00007ffe194e9882                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00628866 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00094722
[103] 0x00007ffe194baa41                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00436801 iqm::Iqm::create+00007777
[104] 0x00007ffe18d92de5           D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00077285 ioReadLine+00000501
[105] 0x00007ffe18d92bb5           D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00076725 ioReadLine+00000165
[106] 0x00007ffe18da2970           D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00141680 mnGetCommandLineBuffer+00000288
[107] 0x00007ffe18da2e02           D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00142850 mnParser+00000466
[108] 0x00007ffe19337226                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00422438 mcr_set_enableReadingFromStdin+00013622
[109] 0x00007ffe192e89a3                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00100771 mcrFunctionSignature::set_signature+00079731
[110] 0x00007ffe19306230                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00221744 mwboost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::`default constructor closure'+00017584
[111] 0x00007ffe19511e0a                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00794122 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::execute+00000074
[112] 0x00007ffe193319ad                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00399789 services::lmgr::exception::LicensingStartupException::~LicensingStartupException+00006861
[113] 0x00007ffe194e9882                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00628866 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00094722
[114] 0x00007ffe194bbd86                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00441734 iqm::Iqm::create+00012710
[115] 0x00007ffe194bb472                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00439410 iqm::Iqm::create+00010386
[116] 0x00007ffe1932072c                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00329516 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00010380
[117] 0x00007ffe19321165                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00332133 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00012997
[118] 0x00007ffe1931e930                   D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00321840 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00002704
[119] 0x00007ffe3f5a85da D:\matlab2022a\bin\win64\mwboost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.dll+00034266 mwboost::thread::swap+00000074
[120] 0x00007ffee0106c0c                   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll+00158732 recalloc+00000092
[121] 0x00007ffee10f54e0                   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+00087264 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000016
[122] 0x00007ffee272485b                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00018523 RtlUserThreadStart+00000043
```

Maybe the .NET Framework was updated and definitions were updated.
And I've read on other forums that maybe reinstalling Graphics card will fix it. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you submit a ticket to the MathWorks?  I’m not sure why you post your crash report here, not like we can do anything about it. The MathWorks make the software, and you pay them for the software, they’ll get you going again.

Comment: What @CrisLuengo said, and uninstall/reinstall the windows updates (or windows). Pointing fingers (to M$ or mathworks) aside, they did work prior to the updates, didn't they?